# What is this 1998 lego piece for F-22?

Tags: part-identification

Can someone help me identify what set this is from? I've tried searching multiple different things on Google and Bricklink and haven't been able to find this piece. It was in with a set of random pieces that was bought at a yard sale. The F-22 stickers on it may not be from the original set but they were on it when I bought it. The only thing I can find written on it is copyright LEGO Group 1998[image]

Comment: Fun fact: this makes a passable decorative sword handle, but a lousy actually usable sword handle.

Answer (score 22):

It is [Electric, Light & Sound 4 x 20 x 5 Insectoid Stinger](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x239&idColor=10#T=C&C=10) which was available in [4 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x239&in=S) from Insectoids series. Stickers are custom.

Comment: Thank you! Too bad a lot of the pieces aren't here.